# commonmarker error message showing up in terminal

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

Whenever I use terminal to do a certain task, for example,
`brew cask install vscodium` or `bundle show minima (jekyll)`
my terminal keeps telling me this:

> Ignoring commonmarker-0.17.13 because its extensions are not built.
>   Try: gem pristine commonmarker --version 0.17.13

What do I need to update to get rid of this error message?

Comment: Literally what the message says is to enter in the terminal ` gem pristine commonmarker --version 0.17.13`.  Sometimes ruby gems get stale and you need a fresh copy.  You can also to gem pristine --all to refresh all copies.

Comment: I tried follow the error message as well as gem pristine --all, none of them works, all gives out one error message, "you dont have the permission to write to directory (directory name)" even I used sudo. Here is a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/zRbJBgV).

Comment: You need to change ownership of that directory to give yourself permissions.  What OS are you on?

Comment: I think I did it. I went into the local jekyll project folder and manually added `gem 'commonmarker'`, then I run bundle from terminal. and it shows me this when I check : `➜  slowpacedcoding git:(gh-pages) ✗ bundle info commonmarker
  * commonmarker (0.17.13)
 Summary: CommonMark parser and renderer. Written in C, wrapped in Ruby.
 Homepage: http://github.com/gjtorikian/commonmarker
 Path: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/commonmarker-0.17.13`